# Подскажите как сделать чтобы содержимое открывалось у всех div

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таких блоков у меня много, а открывается только один помогите сделать чтобы открывалось на всех блоках 
И если можете то покажите как сделать стрелки вверх и вниз

```js
var dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown__label');
var dropdown__list = document.querySelector('.dropdown__list');


dropdown.onclick = function(){
 dropdown__list.classList.toggle('db')
};
```

```css
.dropdown__label {
  position: relative; }

.dropdown__list {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 20px; }

.dropdown__item {
  padding: 0; }
  .dropdown__item a {
    color: #333333;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 36px;
    white-space: nowrap; }
    .dropdown__item a:hover {
      color: #e60146;
      text-decoration: none; }

.dropdown__label {
  color: #000;
  width: 290px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 29px;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #f5f0eb;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
      -ms-flex-pack: start;
          justify-content: flex-start; }
  .dropdown__label:after {
    content: '';
    background-image: url("../img/select-bottom.png");
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 10px;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 12px;
    height: 10px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; }

.db {
  display: block;
  position: relative; }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown__label">Some text</div>
  <ul class="dropdown__list">
    <li class="dropdown__item"><a href="#">ACRA Mid-rise MMR</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown__item"><a href="#">Muse Mid-rise MRL</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown__item"><a href="#">Solon Premium Mid-rise MRL</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Я поправил предыдущий ответ по этой же теме, посмотрите.

Comment: @meine у меня код почему то не работал :(

Comment: @meine пришлось самому писать :(((

Comment: @meine можете мой вариант дополнить только на чистом js ? и стрелочки сделать ?

Comment: Почему не работает? А Вы как его подключали вообще?

Comment: @meine весь код перетащил себе файл

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, еще раз ответ по тому вопросу, скопируйте всё и проверьте. Так же убедитесь, что классы одинаковые.

Comment: @meine ок только я весь htmlб css, js скопировал

Comment: Это то, что нужно, а теперь выложите весь скопированный код сюда.

Comment: @meine подождите пожалуйста минутку

Comment: @meine добавил тут все работает можете объяснить почему так происходит ?

Answer (score -1):

```js
class Dropdown {
  constructor(node) {
    this.node = node;

    if (!this.node) return;

    this.onLabel = this.onLabel.bind(this);

    this.label = this.node.querySelector(".dropdown__label");

    this.label.addEventListener("click", this.onLabel, false);
  }

  isOpen() {
    return this.node.classList.contains("dropdown_open");
  }

  onLabel() {
    this.isOpen() ? this.node.classList.remove("dropdown_open") : this.node.classList.add("dropdown_open");
  }
}

[...document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown")].forEach(node => new Dropdown(node));
```

```css
.dropdown_open .dropdown__list{
 display: block;
}

.dropdown__list{
 display: none;
 }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown__label">Some text</div>
  <ul class="dropdown__list">
    <li class="dropdown__item">Some text #2</li>
    <li class="dropdown__item">Some Text #3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown__label">Some text</div>
  <ul class="dropdown__list">
    <li class="dropdown__item">Some text #2</li>
    <li class="dropdown__item">Some Text #3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @meine  тут работает почему у меня тогда не работает ?!

Comment: Я не телепат, чтобы ответить на Ваш вопрос, дополните ответ этим кодом, не стоит его писать как ответ.

Comment: @meine можете тогда мой код на чистом js дополнить чтобы работало больше чем 1 элемент ?